# React Datepicker value is Undefined

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

Building a simple ToDo list app in ReactJS. Using Datepicker to set a due date for tasks but the value comes back as undefined. I've done a lot of research but can't figure this one out. Abbreviated code below:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import TaskDataService from "../services/task.service";
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';

import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';    

export default class AddTask extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.onChangeTitle = this.onChangeTitle.bind(this);
            this.onChangeDescription = this.onChangeDescription.bind(this);
            this.onChangeDate = this.onChangeDate.bind(this);
            this.saveTask = this.saveTask.bind(this);
            this.newTask = this.newTask.bind(this);
    
            this.state = {
                id: null,
                title: "",
                description: "",
                completed: false,
                startDate: new Date(),
    
                submitted: false
            };
        }
    
        onChangeTitle(e) {
            this.setState({
                title: e.target.value
            });
        }
    
        onChangeDescription(e) {
            this.setState({
                description: e.target.value
            });
        }
    
        onChangeDate(e) {
            this.setState({
                startDate: e
            })
        }
    
        saveTask() {
            var data = {
                title: this.state.title,
                description: this.state.description,
                date: this.state.startDate
            };
    
            TaskDataService.create(data)
                .then(response => {
                    this.setState({
                        id: response.data.id,
                        title: response.data.title,
                        description: response.data.description,
                        completed: response.data.completed,
                        startDate: response.data.date,
    
                        submitted: true
                    });
                    console.log(response.data);
                })
                .catch(e => {
                    console.log(e);
                });
        }
    
        newTask() {
            this.setState({
                id: null,
                title: "",
                description: "",
                completed: false,
                startDate: "",
    
                submitted: false
            });
        }
    
        render() {
            return (
                <div className="submit-form">
                    {this.state.submitted ? (
                        <div>
                            <h4>Task submitted successfully!</h4>
                            <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.newTask}>
                                Add
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    ) : (
                        <div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="title">Title</label>
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    className="form-control"
                                    id="title"
                                    required
                                    value={this.state.title}
                                    onChange={this.onChangeTitle}
                                    name="title"
                                />
                            </div>
    
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="description">Description</label>
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    className="form-control"
                                    id="description"
                                    required
                                    value={this.state.description}
                                    onChange={this.onChangeDescription}
                                    name="description"
                                />
                            </div>
    
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="startDate">Start Date</label>
                                <DatePicker
                                    selected={ this.state.startDate }
                                    onChange={ this.onChangeDate }
                                    name="startDate"
                                    dateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy"
                                />
                            </div>
    
                            <button onClick={this.saveTask} className="btn btn-success">
                                Submit
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    )}
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

The title, description, and status attributes for each task work fine - but not the date, which comes back undefined in the logs as soon as I hit the Submit button. Any ideas?

Comment: Need to include your imports/version numbers for the controls-- MUI 5 DatePicker is very different from MUI 4 DatePicker, or perhaps you're using a different DatePicker entirely. Lots of stuff can be going wrong that can't be determined from the code sample provided alone.

Comment: @C.Helling - My mistake, thanks for pointing that out. Included my imports. package.json shows datepicker v4.8.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out on my own. I had to go into a different module and add a .toISOString line:

```
onChangeDate(e) {
    const startDate = e.target.value;

    this.setState(prevState => ({
        currentTask: {
            ...prevState.currentTask,
            startDate: startDate.toISOString()
        }
    }));
}
```

Once I added ".toISOString" to this component that adds tasks, I was able to get a defined date value. I'm wrangling with other issues but at least now I have a defined date value to work with.